# Utilizing a Func to improve reflection performance for generic types

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I've been doing some investigatory work improving the performance of methods invoked using reflection based on the article and comments on Jon Skeet's blog here.

http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/

Based on one of the comments (formatting is broken in the blog comments) I have the following method.

```
private static Func<T, object, object> MagicMethod<T>(MethodInfo method)
{
  var parameter = method.GetParameters().Single();
  var instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "instance");
  var argument = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "argument");

  var methodCall = Expression.Call(
      instance,
      method,
      Expression.Convert(argument, parameter.ParameterType));

  return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object, object>>(
         Expression.Convert(methodCall, typeof(object)),
         instance,
         argument).Compile();
}
```

Which I can use to return dynamically invoked methods like the one in the example code.

```
private static readonly MethodInfo IndexOfMethod =
        typeof(string).GetMethod("IndexOf", new[] { typeof(char) });

public static object IndexOf(string s, char c)
{
    var i = MagicMethod<string>(IndexOfMethod);
    return i(s,c);         
}
```

This should be good and quick.

I'm trying to apply the approach now to generic methods like `Enumerable.Cast<T>` but can't seem to get anywhere.

I have my `MethodInfo`.

```
private static readonly MethodInfo CastMethod =
        typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast");
```

But I am now lost in the syntax. I can't use the static `Enumerable` type as a generic type argument so I don't know what to do.

Could someone give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

The example needs a little work.  The result of `MagicMethod<string>(IndexOfMethod)` should be stored.  As shown, you will rebuild and re-compile that delegate each time that code runs.  You probably want something more like below that stored the delegate in a static variable so that it isn't re-created each time.

```
private static readonly MethodInfo IndexOfMethod =
    typeof(string).GetMethod("IndexOf", new[] { typeof(char) });

private static readonly Func<string, object, object> MagicCache =
    MagicMethod<string>(IndexOfMethod);

public static object IndexOf(string s, char c)
{
    var i = MagicCache;
    return i(s, c);
}
```

To your question, one way to do it is to start by capturing the generic method definition.  Get the MethodInfo of the call with any type specified, and then call GetGenericMethodDefinition to get the MethodInfo for the generic definition.

Then you can use a generic static variable to cache the delegate. Since the static initializer runs only the first time the type is accessed, the delegate is created and cached one time per type.  Once for `CastMethodCache<int>`, once for `CastMethodCache<string>`, etc.

Finally, call it from a generic method to get and pass in the type information.

This technique works well if the calling code will be generic.  If, instead, the calling code determines the type based on a type variable, you will need a different technique for caching the generated generic delegates.

```
private static readonly MethodInfo CastMethodBase =
    ((Func<IEnumerable, IEnumerable<object>>)Enumerable.Cast<object>)
        .Method
        .GetGenericMethodDefinition();

private static class CastMethodCache<T>
{
    internal static Func<IEnumerable, IEnumerable<T>> CastMethod =
         (Func<IEnumerable, IEnumerable<T>>)CastMethodBase
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T))
            .CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<IEnumerable, IEnumerable<T>>));
}

public static IEnumerable<T> CastWrap<T>(IEnumerable value)
{
    return CastMethodCache<T>.CastMethod.Invoke(value);
}
```

Comment: That certainly clears things up a bit thank you. I'm wondering whether it would be more flexible to use a dictionary to cache the methodinfo's so that multiple enumerable methods , Cast, FirstOrDefault etc could be stored in one location. 

Could you show an example where type is passed as a variable?

Comment: You don't want to cache the MethodInfo, you want to cache the delegate (the `Func<>` variable.  I can't show an example at the moment, but if I get some time later I will post one.